creating a workflow in MS teams , When a Jenkins pipeline triggers a job and end, it should notify to Teams channel , How toset upa workflow for this
creating a workflow in MS teams , When a Jenkins pipeline triggers a job and end,  it should notify to Teams channel , How to set up a workflow for this ,  pls hlp
I would like to know how to create a teams workflow for this
I have searched foe the automate/instant template, but I could n't find the correct one

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
